# implicit else compiler optimization

Tags: c, compiler-optimization

I want to know if there is way for the compiler to understand that two `if` statements can't be true at the same time, and to add an "implicit else". For example in this code sample:

```
int main() {
    char c;
    scanf_s("%c", &c, 1);
    if (c == '1') {
        printf("received 1\n");
    }

    if (c == '2') {
        printf("received 2\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`c` can't be `'1'` *and* `'2'`, but after compiling in Visual Studio and disassembling I noticed that it will check the second `if`, no matter what.

Comment: Check a release build.

Comment: What answer are you expecting, besides *"it's possible, but depends on compiler"*?

Comment: This can not be aswered in general without knowing the exact code and the compiler. If you have a specific use case in mind, I'll recommend checking the generated assembly.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I checked the release build.

Comment: @user694733 Maybe no compiler does this, because it assumes that the var can change (for example in another thread)

Comment: @yeger - It cannot make such an assumption. The way the C standard is written is very single thread oriented. It's in fact a cause for bad "optimizations" in multi-threaded code.

Comment: unless a variable is `volatile`, it can't change values unexpectedly

Comment: Please correct your tags, the code cannot be C *and* C++, they are two different languages. Kindly pick one and edit the tags to suit.

Comment: @Toby - It simply cannot be C++, due to the use of `scanf_s`

Comment: Unless someone teaches the compiler very specifically what scanf and printf do, scanf might store a pointer to c in some global variable, and printf might modify c through that pointer. If you replace printf with something less opaque, gcc does the optimization.

Comment: @StoryTeller Obvs. But it's better to educate the asker on proper usage of SO than keep editing their questions. Teach a man to fish etc.

Comment: @Toby - Your'e more optimistic than me in that regard. I don't think the downpour of "C/C++" questions will ever lessen.

Comment: Are you low on disc space? Why not use `} else if ...`? The time you have written this question, you could have a look at the assembly code generated or - better - just added the `else`.

Comment: This question is basically about *abstract machine* and *observable behaviour*. Maybe someone could find a good dupe, I could not.

Comment: You code invokes UB. [The `%c` in the `scanf_s` requires a third argument denoting the number of characters to read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx). `scanf_s("%c", &c);` → `scanf_s("%c", &c, 1);`

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know if there is way for the compiler to understand that two if statements can't be true at the same time, and to add an "implicit else".

Yes there is: the Intel C compiler `icc` 17 does, as can been verified with [Matt Godbolt's Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/wLQQFK), but neither clang nor gcc seem to perform this optimization.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer in the context of LLVM/CLANG because I am little familiar with its internals.

If you do turn on the mem2reg optimization in opt, it will treat c as a temporary rather than a variable on the stack (in the phases before register allocation).

There the optimizer can make the required assumption and in that case say the second if was inside the first one, it would be removed by DCE.

But I can't think of any pass from the LLVM suite that would add an "elseif".

The same cannot be said about other compilers like gcc/msvc.

Answer (score 0):

Could a compiler *theoretically* perform the optimization that you suggest? Yes, it absolutely could, but making sure the semantic analysis required to detect such *safe* scenarios in the compiler are bug free is decidedly non-trivial, and the question is whether the development effort couldn't be spent better elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Since `scanf_s()` is given a pointer to the variable `c` this variable can't anymore be considered as a local variable. A priori, the function could store this pointer somewhere and any other functions (unknown to the compiler) could store something via this pointer, like for example the call to `printf("received 1\n")`.

In other words, the compiler can't do this optimization unless it knows what the function `scanf_s()` and `printf()` are doing.